# Timing with animations in the node editor

Tags: animation, node-editor, compositing-nodes

Could someone please tell me how to change the timing on composite animations? I'm making a mask from one video and putting it onto another video, but I want the mask to start partway through the second (background) video, but haven't been able to figure it out. Everything was successful except for the bit about timing. Thanks again.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by composite animations? Do you mean animations made of multiple node trees or animations that you have loaded into the Compositor/VSE?